# How to update html element in ng-repeat collection every second automatically

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, timeout, angularjs-ng-repeat, intervals

In my controller I have a function that receives data from API every 2 seconds($interval). This data is rendered and displayed to user. When I get positive numbers from my API I want to set background color in HTML to green for 1 second and return it  to original color. If it is negative, set background color to red for 1 second, and so on...

controller.js

```
function checkForUpdatedIndices(){
  dataService.getIndices().then(function(res){
    $scope.recentIndeces = res.data;        
 });}

 var indicesTimer = setInterval(checkForUpdatedIndices,2000);
 checkForUpdatedIndices();
```

My HTML:

```
<ul id="ctr_indices">
        <li class="cl_indeces" ng-repeat="i in recentIndeces track by $index">
            <span class="itemname">{{i.itemName}}</span>
            <span class="itemlastvalue">{{i.itemLastValue}}</span>
            <span class="itemchange">{{i.itemChange}}</span>
            <span class="itempercentage">{{i.itemPercentageChange}}</span>
        </li>
 </ul>
```

When i.itemLastValue contains "+" I want to see it green for 1 second and after that change it back to original color.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do this using `ng-style` directive. set this style like this

```
ng-style="{'background-color' : i.color}"
```

and call a function inside `ng-init` and pass the item as a parameter

```
<span class="itemlastvalue" ng-style="{'background-color' : i.color}" ng-init="setColor(i)">{{i.itemLastValue}}</span>
```

In the function assign the color according to the condition and use `timeout` function to reverse it to the original value

```
$scope.setColor = function(i){
    if( i.itemLastValue == "+"){
      i.color = 'green'
    }
    else if( i.itemLastValue == "-"){
      i.color = 'red'
    }

    $timeout(function(){
       i.color = "white" // what ever the original value 
    },1000)
}
```

**UPDATED**

the second scenario is removing the `ng-init` function and call the function inside `checkForUpdatedIndices`

```
function checkForUpdatedIndices(){
  dataService.getIndices().then(function(res){
    $scope.recentIndeces = res.data; 
    setColor()       
 });
}

function setColor(){
   var backUp = angular.copy($scope.recentIndeces);
   for(var i=0; i<= $scope.recentIndeces.length-1; i++){
      if( $scope.recentIndeces[i].itemLastValue == "+"){
        $scope.recentIndeces[i].color = 'green'
      }
      else if( $scope.recentIndeces[i].itemLastValue == "-"){
        $scope.recentIndeces[i].color = 'red'
      }
   }
   $timeout(function(){
      $scope.recentIndeces =  angular.copy(backUp);
   },1000)
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. In your example setColor function was called only once. I need to update it every time the i.itemLastValue is changed.

Comment: when does it changed

Comment: every 2 seconds. I send request with setInterval to my API.    var indicesTimer = setInterval(checkForUpdatedIndices,2000);
 checkForUpdatedIndices();